# How do you write "Love Life" in mandarin?

Tags: translation, grammar

I am making a poster and looking to say "Love Life" in several different languages. I didn't want to use Google translate as it's not the most accurate translator. I just want to give people a positive message of Hope, you never know who out there might be in need and by doing it in various languages i can make sure lots of people get the message.

Comment: My friends use the word "Love Life" to refer to romantic relationships, but I think that is not what you want. You need to add more explanations to describe what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend the meaning of “life” in “love life” as the one in “get a life”, your phrase could be translated into 热爱生活.
If “life” means the opposite of death, it could be translated into 珍惜生命.

Answer (score 0):

Love (v) : 愛

life (n) : 生命

"Love life" = "愛生命". To make it more idiomatic in Chinese, you can use "熱愛生命"

Notice:

"Love" (adjectival noun) + "life" (n) is  "愛情生活" in Chinese. It is different from "Love (v) + "life" (n)

Answer (score 0):

My view is the "Love" as used by OP in his message is in the context of "cherish" or "treasure"

That is "Cherish / Treasure Life", as OP said "...a positive message of Hope", for where Life is cherished, there is Hope.

Thus I feel that 珍惜生命 is more appropriate for OP's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, 珍爱生命？

珍爱: 珍惜(cherish)，爱护(take good care of)

生命: life